# A test of my understanding of identification

Tags: regression, linear-model, identifiability

I've been asking a few questions about identification lately, so forgive me for another one:

Throughout this question, **let $\mathbb P$ denote the set of probability distributions consistent with the relevant model**. Let $B$ be the set of posible values that $\beta$ can take.

If I understand it correctly:

> **Identifiability.** the parameter (vector) $\beta$ in a model (which has only $\beta$ as a parameter) with observable variables $X,Y$ is **identifiable**, if there is a **bijection** between $\mathbb P$ and $B$.

I am also told, that in the linear regression model
$$y=X\beta+\epsilon$$

The parameter $\beta$ is identified if $E(X^T\epsilon)=0$, since we can then multiply both sides by $X^T$, and get:
$$E(X^Ty)=E(X^TX)\beta+\underbrace { E(X^T\epsilon)}_{\text{drops out}}$$

**However, my question is this: Is there really a bijection between probability distributions and values of $\beta$ here?**

It seems to me that there is not, since the requirement that the expectations of these expressions coincide, does not put any restriction on the shape of their distribution, other than on their mean. For example, $X^Ty$ could be normally distributed or $t$-distributed, or cauchy, or even bimodal, so long as its expectation is equal to $E(X^TX)\beta$.

Surely we can determine $\beta$ from the probability distribution $P\in\mathbb P$, simply by taking these expectations and calculating $\beta$ using the above equation. However, This is not an injective map, since many different distributions lead to the same value for $\beta$. Hence it is also not a bijection.

> **This gives a paradox**: on the one hand $\beta$ in the linear model is supposedly identifiable, but on the other hand, according to the definition and my argument just presented, it cannot be.

**What is wrong with my argument?**

Comment: Since the least squares estimator is an estimating equation, there are no distributional assumptions on X or Y. $\mathbb{P}$ would have to consider the very, very large family of distributions where $E(Y|X) = \hat{\beta}X$ in this instance. It will not be a unique mapping, for sure. Many families of probability models can/could apply to a single set of least-squares coefficients.

Comment: @AdamO, so what is your answer to my paradox?

Comment: I am saying a single $\beta$ vector maps to many probability models, and each of those probability models generates data which map back to the $\beta$. Are you thinking that somehow those probability models would generate data having means leading to parameter estimates other than $\beta$?

Comment: To identify structural quantities we need that two different structural quantities imply two different distributions, not the other way around. That is , in your case, $P(\beta_1) = P(\beta_2) \implies \beta_1 = \beta_2$, where $P(\beta_1)$ is the joint probability of observed variables implied by $\beta = \beta_1$. In other words, we need to make sure two different quantities cannot occur under the same probability distribution. Thus, it doesn't matter if  $P$ is t or normal, as long as $P(\beta_1) = P(\beta_2) \implies \beta_1 = \beta_2$. I will try to elaborate more on it later.